# Difference between object and record type

Tags: oracle

I am just curious whats the difference between object and record type in oracle, More specifically between the below declarations

```
create type emp2_oty is object 
(
 empno  number,
 ename  varchar2(20),
 deptno number
);

create type emp2_nt is table of emp2_oty;
```

and

```
type emp2_oty is record
(
 empno  number,
 ename  varchar2(20),
 deptno number
);

create type emp2_nt is table of emp2_oty;
```

Please elaborate.

Comment: basically, record is a pl/sql type, and object types are UDTs that can exist outside pl/sql.  Which one you choose depends on your needs really.

Comment: Objects also have methods, while records only have fields; but the SQL vs. PL/SQL is more relevant here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The OBJECT type can be stored in the database and can be used in both SQL and PL/SQL

Answer (score 47):

- record:

  ```
     Cannot be stored in the database.
     Cannot be recursively referenced.
     Cannot have logic defined as part of their definition.
  ```
- object:

  ```
     Can be stored as a database table column or as an entire row.
     Can be recursively referenced using the SELF parameter.
     Can have logic defined as part of their definition using member methods.
  ```

Answer (score 0):

> [Understanding PL/SQL Records](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/collections.htm#i20716)
>
> Records are composed of a group of fields, similar to the columns in a row.The %ROWTYPE attribute lets you declare a PL/SQL record that represents a row in a database table, without listing all the columns.

Basically, if you are familiar with C/C++ or similar languages, you could tell that Records are nothing but structures (i.e a data type that can be used to group items of possibly different types into a single type) **they can not have methods within.** Objects on the other hand are completely different:

> [Oracle Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14260/adobjint.htm#ADOBJ001)
>
> Oracle object types are user-defined types that make it possible to model real-world entities

**1. Objects Can Encapsulate Operations Along with Data**

*Database tables contain only data. Objects can include the ability to perform operations (i.e methods) that are likely to be needed on that data (e.g a purchase order object might include a method to sum the cost of all the items purchased).*

**2. Objects Can Represent Part-Whole Relationships**

*An object can have other objects as attributes, and the attribute objects can have their own object attributes too. An entire parts-list hierarchy can be built up in this way from interlocking object types.*

**3. Objects Are Efficient**

3.1 Object types and their methods are stored with the data in the database, so they are available for any application to use.

3.2 You can fetch and manipulate a set of related objects as a single unit (e.g when you select a customer object and get the customer's name, phone, and the multiple parts of his address in a single round-trip between the client and the server) .